# Quantum information references

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, education, quantum-computer

I was hoping you guys could recommend reading material on quantum information. I have a good background in quantum mechanics, including in foundational issues, as covered in Ballentine's *Quantum Mechanics*.

I am interested in the intersection of quantum information and quantum foundations, such as in the works of C. Fuchs and in the research of the Perimeter Institute. While I prefer a more rigorous text, I'm trying to be as open as possible and would enjoy any suggestions or recommended reads.

Currently, I am reading the book by Busch, Lahti and Grebowski, notes on ArXiv by Keyl and also the notes by Preskill.

Answer (score 9):

> This answer contains some additional resources that may be useful. **Please note that answers which simply list resources but provide no details are strongly discouraged by [the site's policy on resource recommendation questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)**. This answer is left here to contain additional links that do not yet have commentary.

- [Quantum Computer Science : An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521876583) by Mermin is a really fine book. 'The clearest and most straightforward introduction that I've seen'.
- [John Preskill's lecture notes](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/people/preskill/ph229/), though it does not provide answers to its exercises.
- [Lectures by H. Mabuchi at Stanford](http://www.stanford.edu/~hmabuchi/AP225-2008/).
- [Lectures by R. Sasaki](http://www.stanford.edu/~rsasaki/AP226/AP226.html).
- You might like quantiki http://www.quantiki.org/, it is a portal dedicated to quantum information theory. It contains interesting stuff ( e.g, video abstracts of papers).
- Nielsen, Chuang: *Quantum Computation and Quantum Information*.
- Bengtsson, Życzkowski, *Geometry of Quantum States*.
- Mark M. Wilde on quantum information (Shannon) theory on the arxiv: 
  [From Classical to Quantum Shannon Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1445). It is essentially the same as his published book: [Quantum Information Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CARI9KY)

Answer (score 7):

The best recommendation I can offer isn't for a book, but a series of video lectures. The Perimeter Institute and the University of Waterloo offer a Masters program in theoretical physics called Perimeter Scholars International (full disclosure: I graduated from PSI in 2010), and videos of all PSI lectures are posted on PI's video site, [PIRSA](http://pirsa.org/). One of the PSI courses, Rob Spekkens' course on quantum foundations, sounds like it'd be the exact kind of thing you're looking for. The most recent offering of his class can be found [here](http://pirsa.org/C12002).

Comment: I know of these too. I like Spekkens' course and also Ben Schumacher's course. Chris Fuchs lectures are very inspiring and informative.

Comment: Would you happen to know any references for Statistical Mechanics books which introduce stat mech from the perspective of information theory?

Comment: The online book ''Classical and Quantum Mechanics via Lie algebras'' (http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/0810.1019) has in Chapter 10: Models, statistics, and measurements a discussion on the relation of statistical mechanics to information theory

Answer (score 7):

**Scott Aaronson** has just published a new [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B4V6IZK) about quantum computing. According to the nice introductary comments the author himself has written to his book [here](http://motls.blogspot.de/2013/04/scott-aaronson-quantum-computing-since.html) (scroll down to the second half of the article if you only want to learn about the book), it should explain and introduce both the physical and mathematical concepts quantum computing is based on.

Maybe reading this book can help [students](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60599/2751) in choosing the appropriat mathematical and phyics lectures to be heard in what reasonable order to finally being able to do research in quantum computing too.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend the lecture notes from these two courses taught by John Watrous. They can be found at http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/lecture-notes.html from when he taught at the University of Calgary. I've used the notes from his Theory of Quantum Information course numerous times for a quick reference on some more difficult concepts.