# I am interested in learning Quantum Computing what should I do?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, education, quantum-computer

I wish to learn about quantum computing which seems to be a topic of hot research and overall just intrigues me. I have a strong background in discrete mathematics and number theory. And am a pretty proficient programmer and strong problem solver. What math and physics knowledge (and in what order) should I work to be able to get the knowledge necessary for studying Quantum Computing?

Comment: Both computer architecture and algorithm design are in my interest

Comment: Hi frogeyedpeas, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Educational questions like this aren't really what this site is for (well, we'll see what the community thinks), but you could definitely bring this up in [chat].

Comment: I should have guessed, they have the same rules over at the math forum where I spend most of my time

Comment: can you move this over?

Comment: To chat? No, the system doesn't have a way to move questions from the site to the chat rooms. But you can just join the room and post a message. (Don't worry if there's nobody there; your message will stick around so anyone who joins the chat room later will see it.)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I guess he wants it migrated to maths SE, could this be done?

Comment: For a related book recommendation post, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20260/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks for this helpful link, now I have put there what I wanted to say (not sure if the level is right for the OP there) and linked to this question. However, I still strongly disagree with David Zaslavsky continuisly and unilaterally closing questions about different things very useful to student like this. Other physicists seem not to feel that offended by the presence of such questions, they dont care, and to students they are useful. David, and of course some people who rather represent the SE network and philosophy than the opinion of practising physicists, are the only ones

Comment: who feel offended by educational/study material/reference request questions. I wonder why it is only these people who are allowed to determine the game. Manishearth rather represents and enforces the interests of the SE company too than making the site useful for a community of physicists...

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Maybe Scott Aaronson would give you directly some advice in the comments below his [guest post](http://motls.blogspot.de/2013/04/scott-aaronson-quantum-computing-since.html) about his new book

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This book by Nielsen and Chuang](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107002176) 
is easy enough to read at the beginner's level but totally comprehensive.

Comment: Scott Aaronson has just written a new [book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00B4V6IZK?tag=lubosmotlsref-20&camp=213761&creative=393545&linkCode=bpl&creativeASIN=B00B4V6IZK&adid=1K3V1T98W9RBR8HK3B6E&&ref-refURL=http%3A%2F%2Fmotls.blogspot.com%2F2013%2F04%2Fscott-aaronson-quantum-computing-since.html) about quantum computing. According to the nice introductary comments the author has written [here](http://motls.blogspot.com/2013/04/scott-aaronson-quantum-computing-since.html) scroll down to the second half of the article if you only want to learn about the book, it should explain the physical and

Comment: mathematicel concepts quantum computing is based on explain at a not purely popular level but Lenny Susskind lecture intermediate level. Maybe reading this book can help in choosing the appropriat mathematical and phyics lectures to be heard in a meaningful order to finally being able to do research in quantum computing.