# What is a good book for quantum mechanics and quantum computation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I am looking for a book in quantum computers for self-learning.The kind of book that teaches quantum-mechanics + quantum-computation.
I have basic understanding in calculus , linear-algebra (like matrix addition,multiplication) and classical mechanics that is taught in the Advanced level.Just basic , like I don't understand (but know) the logic behind Maxwells equation or laplace operators etc.

But , as I am a CS student, my basic goal is understanding quantum computers as you should realize.

So what book is best for this purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33215/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60599/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20260/2451

Comment: No , that op didn't want to learn quantum computing too.

Answer (score 0):

[Quantum Computing since Democritus](http://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/) was useful to me, coming from a similar background.

It first observes that one only needs a few principles of QM to think about quantum computation, and then launches into the complexity theory underlying the abilities of theoretical quantum computers.