# Quantum Computer Implementation

Tags: quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-computer

I recently finished my bachelor in nanotechnology and am rather interested in quantum computation.

I've already looked at the recommendation threads for this topic, but they tend to be about theoretical introductions.

I've been wondering if there are any books or texts out there with a focus on the hardware of quantum computers, i.e., physical implementations of qubits, measurements and quantum gates and their advantages and drawbacks.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20260/2451 and links therein.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06560 This article is a nice guide to quantum computing from an engineers' perspective.

Comment: You might be better off asking here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quantum Computation is mostly written in terms of quantum gates, which translates more directly to hardware implementation. It will probably be easy for you to understand it. Steps you need to take:

1. Understand how to compute the quantum way: Know how bra-ket works, that's easy to learn. I highly recommend Quantum Computation by Nielsen and Chuang.
2. Get to know the Bell's basis(qubits) and basic quantum gates.
3. Know how to input and compute(measure) from a quantum circuit. Here is a [simulation package](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/jose.luis.gomez/quantum/index.htm) of quantum gates.

Finally, physical implementation of quantum computers is still a very new field. Your best bet is to look for papers on experiments that test the theories, or get in touch with insiders. When I was at Perimeter Institute there was experimenters meeting with my advisors to discuss experimental tests for the PBR theorem. Maybe you can try to get in touch with the folks there by emailing them.

Goodluck.