# Any Books about Superconducting Quantum Computing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, quantum-computer

I'm an undergraduate majored in physics and I'm quite interested in superconducting quantum computing. Are there any books or maybe reviews about this field (suitable for beginners)?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20260/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You specifically ask about *superconducting* quantum computing. Does this mean you are more interested in the technology and engineering of this type of quantum computer, rather than the theory of quantum computing in general ?

Comment: @gandalf61 yeah that's what I mean. I'm now reading "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information" by Nielsen & Chuang, from this book I can get an overview. So I want to ask if there are any books specifically focused on superconducting quantum computing.

Comment: @Dylan_Wu If you don't get any suggestions here you could try asking at QC stack exchange https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @gandalf61 thanks, it helps a lot