# QM books with an emphasis on quantum information/computing

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, education, quantum-computer

What is a good intro textbook on QM (at the level of Griffith, a standard one year course for undergraduates in physics) that has some focus on quantum information/quantum computing? Maybe even with some exercise that make use of circ or qiskit? Is there something similar the graduate level (again, a textbook for a standard intro course, at the level of Shankar or Sakurai)?

Note that I am not asking about QI/QC books (of which there are many), but books suitable for a standard introductory QM course (for grads or undergrads) that still contain the usual material (say the hydrogen atom, perturbation theory, etc) focus on QI/QC instead of other applications (eg scattering theory).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20260/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I am not looking for QI/QC books (of which there are many), but an intro to QM with some emphasis on QI/QC