# Best books/notes for learning quantum computing for a mathematician with no quantum mechanics background

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, education, quantum-computer

I have a PhD in numerical analysis for PDE, and for this reason I have a very strong background in functional analysis, Hilbert spaces / linear and nonlinear operators, algebra, but also probability.

For job reasons, I need to learn quantum computing at a very "operative" level (I need to write quantum programs, basically), but I am stuck as I feel I am lacking too much of quantum mechanics background.

I can see that there is plenty of material and lecture notes about quantum mechanics, but I feel like the bridge between quantum mechanics and quantum computing is missing somehow. In addition to that, as I think as a mathematician, to me is difficult to understand some concepts while reading the some lecture notes or book.

How can I bridge my background in mathematics to effectively learn quantum computing at an operative level, despite lacking a strong background in quantum mechanics? Can you recommend material that can help me connect the dots between quantum mechanics and quantum computing, particularly from a mathematical perspective?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quantum information references](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20260/quantum-information-references)

Comment: well, if you have questions about the _physics_ connection to the math (e.g., spin, photon polarization,  the Bloch Sphere) ask it here.

Comment: Try David Mermin's book: "Quantum Computer Science: An Introduction." The good news is that Quantum Computing deals almost exclusively with finite dimensional spaces, so you are really just doing a lot of linear algebra with finite dimensional unitary matrices. No need to worry about anything like $[x, p] = i\hbar$, for the most part.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20260/2451 and links therein.

Comment: *Feynmann lectures on physics* have excellent part about basic QM - rarely going beyond two-level systems. I think quantum computing doesn't need more physics knowledge than that.